# get-hotfix on single server

Tags: powershell

first time using powershell and I can't seem to get the below to work - nothing is displayed - I think the script work but I assume I need something to show the results? Any help please:

```
$hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB981872

If($hotfix)
{
$Output = "Hotfix is installed you may proceed"
}
else
{
$Output = "Hotfix is not installed"
}
$hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB981872
```

Thanks Shay - I have updated it as:

```
 write-host "This will check if Hotfix KB979808 is installed on this Server." -ForegroundColor 

Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
write-host "This is required for Windows Server 2008 R2 DFSR Pre-Seeding Robocopying"  -

ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
Write-Host ""

$hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB979808 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If($hotfix1 -match "KB979808")
{
    Write-Host "Hotfix is installed you may proceed" -foregroundcolor "green"
    Write-Host ""
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Hotfix is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix BEFORE"
    Write-host "copying any data" -foregroundcolor "red"
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: Great. One thing though, I would change this line: 'If($hotfix1 -match "KB979808")' to 'If($hotfix1.HotFixID -eq 'KB979808')', or simply 'If($hotfix1)...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code doesn't output anything because you assign it to a variable. Remove the assignment. You are also assigning the command output to $hotfix1 but checking against $hotfix in the if statement. In addition, if the hot-fix cannot be found you'll get an error, so add the -ErrorAction parameter to suppress the error:

```
$hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB981872 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If($hotfix1)
{
   "Hotfix is installed you may proceed"
}
else
{
    "Hotfix is not installed"
}

$hotfix1
```